# Filter Mediator on XPATH Functions

Tags: xpath, filter, wso2-esb

I am facing a problem with my code using Filter mediator and XPATH functions. What I am trying to do in my code is to check if a particular block is empty, do not call/enrich that block and move to another one checks for if it is empty, if not process it and moves to next one and in the end do a commit. Currently I am getting the error as:

FilterMediator Error evaluating XPath expression : fn:exists($body/product/simpleProduct/standardAttributes)

```
My code is as follows:
<inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="STATUS" value="************ REQUEST ***************"/>
         </log>
         <transaction action="new"/>
         <filter xpath="fn:exists($body/product/simpleProduct/standardAttributes)">
          </filter>           
         <enrich>
            <source type="body" clone="true"/>
            <target type="property" property="MSG_PAYLOAD"/>
         </enrich>
         <log level="full"/>
         <xslt key="simpleAttributes"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="STATUS"
                      value="*********INSERTING Simple Product Attributes *************"/>
         </log>

</inSequence>
```

It fails at fn:exists(). Can you help me with your inputs where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the function you use is xpath 2 function. OOTB xpath 2 functions won't work in ESB. If this is xpath2, you have to enable it. To enable xpath 2, for that uncomment synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled=true in synapse.properties file.